# Is it possible to see args or env variables from previous build stage in docker?

Tags: docker

Let's say I have this Dockerfile (multi-stage build):

```
FROM node:18.7-alpine AS deps
ARG SECRET_ARG
ENV SECRET_ARG_ENV_VAR=${SECRET_ARG}

FROM node:18.7-alpine AS final
RUN echo "Hello!"
```

I run the build command:

```
docker build --build-arg SECRET_ARG=$(cat secret.txt) -t my-container .
```

Will it be possible for someone with the image to find the value of `SECRET_ARG` or `SECRET_ARG_ENV_VAR`? I need a build time only environment variable. I tried with `docker inspect`, but I think only stuff from the last build stage was visible. Same with `docker history`.

I know of [Docker build secret information](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information), but it's proven tricky as I need the value at build time with Next.js, so when `next build` runs, it's available. And I haven't found a way to set it as an env variable via the `RUN` command.

What I want is for the env variable `SECRET_ARG_ENV_VAR` to be available during the `deps` build stage, but not at all available during the `final` build stage. And it also needs to be impossible to reverse-engineer its value.

Comment: Yes, someone with the image can see the env vars baked into it. If you want it to be secret, you need to provide it at run time, not build time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How? I tried with `docker inspect`, but I think only stuff from the last build stage was visible. Same with `docker history`.

Comment: Oh if it's a multi-stage build then as you say you only get the last stage's container. But that may still get baked into the Next build somewhere.